# How to use a ~ (relative directory) in my java class?

Tags: java, file-io

I create a temporary file on the server, that someone uploads. While I was testing, It was fine to use the complete home directory path in my machine. But now that I have to deploy it to a server, I tried using a ~, but I get a

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/test/csvFile.csv (No such file or directory)`

how do I use something analogous to a ~ ie short for the home directory in *nix. I am using the java.io.File package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want a temporary file, you should stop caring about which directory this ends up in (usually) and instead use

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("csvFile", ".csv");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
System.getProperty("user.home") ; //will return the path to user home directory.
```

If i understood it correctly you are looking for how to get user dir path

Comment: life.java ^_^ unfortunately Thilo's answer was correct, but I will upvote because its useful!

Answer (score 3):

`~` is deciphered by Unix shell, not by your program. To get the same effect, get the value of "HOME"

```
System.getenv("HOME")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `user.home` system property points to the current user's home directory.

However, you may want to consider [`File.createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead for temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is not a relative directory. `.` is a relative directory. `~` corresponds to the value of the system property `user.home`. However `java.io.File` already contains several methods for temporary files: use those.